# merge rows based on values in a column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    Row-Labels   300    301
0   BLR          1
1   BLR          2      2
2   NSL         
3   RFR          3
4   TNC          22
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
    Row-Labels   300    301
0   BLR          3      2
1   NSL        
2   RFR          3
3   TNC          22
```

That is, I want to merge all rows into one where row-labels column values are same. This merge should be such that the column in the resulting row should sum all values in column A for row-labels value 'BLR' and put other values as it is in the that column of the row if no sum is required.

What I have done so far is something like this:

```
for i in range(300, 301):
    temp_final_df.append(final_df.groupby(['Row-Labels'])['{}'.format(i)].apply(sum).reset_index())
```

But its output is not correct. In short, I want to merge rows such that Row_labels column values become unique. Any other ideas as how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
df.groupby('Row-Labels').sum().replace(0,np.nan)
```

if you dont want np.nan and just blank values:

```
df.groupby('Row-Labels').sum().replace(0,'')
```

Edit:

```
df.groupby('Row-Labels').sum().replace(0,'').reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Row-Labels   300     301
0   BLR          3       2 
1   NSL   
2   RFR          3  
3   TNC          22
```

Comment: this groups the 'Row-Labels' together but values in columns are empty. Meaning, the row values for 'Row-Labels' column are as I want them but columns 300 and 301 are empty

Comment: @rootkit : i have added the output too.pl check if it helps. Thanks